# How to stop threads created by org.asynchttpclient to prevent memory leak?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, asynchttpclient

I am using org.asynchttpclient to post async request.

While shutting down tomcat, I am getting below logs:

> SEVERE: The web application [/test] appears to have started a thread named [pool-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>   Jul 04, 2017 10:53:00 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
>
> SEVERE: The web application [/test] appears to have started a thread named [AsyncHttpClient-2-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>   Jul 04, 2017 10:53:00 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
>
> SEVERE: The web application [/test] appears to have started a thread named [AsyncHttpClient-2-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>   Jul 04, 2017 10:53:00 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>
> SEVERE: The web application [/test] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@71513074]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@4aecc2e8]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

How to close these threads to prevent memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more of a warning and in most times can be ignored. You will see this error when the context is reloaded or shut down. If you are shutting down the server then the JVM will be shutdown also and the os will clean up any memory.
If you want to try and call close on the `AsyncHttpClient` which implements `Closable` it may stop this issue. You will probably have to put a wait in there to let it fully close the connection factory. You can look at the tomcat Lifecycle to add a shutdown handler to handle closing the client.